# Return value from exec(@sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want get the value from `Exec(@sql)` and assign to `@Rowcount(int)`

Here is my query:

```
'SET @RowCount = (select count(*) 
                    FROM dbo.Comm_Services 
                   WHERE CompanyId = '+cast(@CompanyId as char)+' and '+@condition+')'
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

On the one hand you could use sp_executesql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select @rowcount=count(*) from anytable', 
                    N'@rowcount int output', @rowcount output;
```

On the other hand you could use a temporary table:

```
declare @result table ([rowcount] int);
insert into @result ([rowcount])
exec (N'select count(*) from anytable');
declare @rowcount int = (select top (1) [rowcount] from @result);
```

Comment: Very good! Except in SQL 2016 this gives "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rowcount'". It seems ROWCOUNT is a reserved identifier. Search and replace rowcount to row_count works great. Thank you.

Comment: Very good.  However, don't forget to drop the table at the end.

Comment: @Zamir `@result` is a table variable, not a temporary table, so there is no need to drop it. In fact, you cannot drop it, similar to how you can not drop any other variable such as an integer.

Comment: Thank a lot for the comments. Renaming is an option, putting into brackets is the other option I chose in my edited answer. And yes, you can't drop table variables - they exist only inside the variable's scope.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @nReturn int = 0
EXEC @nReturn = Stored Procedure
```

Comment: This works to retrieve the return value of a stored procedure, but not dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Was playing with this today... I believe you can also use `@@ROWCOUNT`, like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Rowcount INT
SET @SQL = 'SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2'
EXEC(@SQL)
SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @Rowcount
```

Then replace the `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2` with your actual select without the count. I'd suggest just putting 1 in your select, like this:

```
SELECT 1
FROM dbo.Comm_Services
WHERE....
....
```

(as opposed to putting SELECT *)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

With this pattern, you can return whatever type or results you are after from the results of your exec statement.

```
declare @result table ([rowcount] int);

insert into @result ([rowcount])
Exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

that's my procedure

```
CREATE PROC sp_count
    @CompanyId sysname,
    @codition sysname
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    CREATE TABLE #ctr
    ( NumRows int )

    DECLARE @intCount int
         , @vcSQL varchar(255)

    SELECT    @vcSQL = ' INSERT #ctr FROM dbo.Comm_Services 
                       WHERE CompanyId = '+@CompanyId+' and '+@condition+')'
    EXEC      (@vcSQL)

    IF @@ERROR = 0
    BEGIN
         SELECT    @intCount = NumRows
         FROM #ctr

         DROP TABLE #ctr
         RETURN @intCount
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
         DROP TABLE #ctr
         RETURN -1
    END
    GO
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you correctly, (i probably don't)

```
'SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*)
                   FROM dbo.Comm_Services
                   WHERE CompanyId = ' + CAST(@CompanyId AS CHAR) + '
                   AND ' + @condition
```

Comment: The variable will be out of scope within the call to `EXEC('...')`.