# How to get value for Temp variable in Sql?

Tags: sql-server

I write a query in sql server i am getting value in a temporary variable, this is my query

```
  declare @tacolumn1 varchar(50)='cargo'
 declare @temp1 varchar(50)
 declare @sql nvarchar(max)
 print @tacolumn1
set @sql=  ('select '+@tacolumn1+' from operatingincome where YEAR(createddate)= 2009')
exec sp_executesql  @sql  
print @temp1
```

from the above @sql has the value , now i want to save that value in @temp1 how can i do that one

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130462/return-value-from-execsql it's very similar to what your trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sp_executesql procedure [can have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188001.aspx) input and output parameters:

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @max_title varchar(30);

SET @IntVariable = 197;
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @max_titleOUT = max(JobTitle) 
   FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.HumanResources.Employee
   WHERE BusinessEntityID = @level';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@level tinyint, @max_titleOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @level = @IntVariable, @max_titleOUT=@max_title OUTPUT;
SELECT @max_title;
```

Comment: it is giving error like : Must declare the scalar variable "@temp1".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check my answer. I fit it.