# Dynamic Parameter for stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table which stores intermediary tables names & final Tables for each main tables listed at column level.Iam trying to write a stored procedure which will accept parameter - main Table name and and give result back the intermediary table names .
Then following query should select few columns from the intermediary table (result of first query)Any help would be great !

I have first part resolved , but second part is an issue :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_dataselect] 

(  
 @MainTable  varchar(20) 
)  
AS
EXEC ('SELECT @ITable =im_table from' +@MainTable)
EXEC ('SELECT * from dbo.' +@ITABLE)
```

-- this does not work .

Comment: What for what concrete database system is this? There are so many - and every one of them does stored procedures a bit differently than the other.... please update your tags accordingly!

Comment: marc_s wants to know whether this is SQL Server, or Oracle, or MySql or.... something else. I am guessing it's SQL Server. Tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I think this is very simular to the issue described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130462/return-value-from-execsql

Comment: Hi this is for MS SQL Server . I am new to this .

Answer (score 0):

Your `@ITable` variable, that you are `SELECT`-ing into in the 1st `EXEC`, is not declared inside the stored procedure. So there is no way to access it in the 2nd `EXEC` statement.

Answer (score 0):

EXEC ('SELECT @ITable =im_table from' +@MainTable)
EXEC ('SELECT * from dbo.' +@ITABLE)

Are two separate queries and the variable @ITABLE declared at the first one ill not be avaiable for the second.

You can try to transform it in a unique query using the first one as subquery for the second.

warning: Using dynamic queries like that at general is a bad idea, try to avoid it or at least learn about dynamic parametric queries.