# Dynamic sql query not working. Sytnax error near EXEC

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Hey so I have an issue at work I am having difficulty with. I am trying to join a table only and only if a certain value is equal to 1. Now I can't use case in this regard as it returns scalar values. So I am left with the situation of using dynamic sql. However I need to EXEC the code inside a select statement but I am not able to do this and I was wondering could someone point me on my way?

So let's say this code is in a select statement

```
      ISNULL(c.Name, (EXEC @sql) as courseName,
```

and this is before it

```
SET @isSelectAll = CASE 
                      WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @coursesectionID csec WHERE csec.Id = -1) 
                      THEN  1
                      ELSE 0
                   END  

SET @sql = CASE WHEN @isSelectAll = 0 
                THEN
                ' SELECT TOP 1 c.Name 
                  from SCS_Course c 
                  INNER JOIN SCS_CourseSection cs 
                     on c.CoursePk = cs.CourseFk    
                  where cs.CourseFk = 
                     (Select cs.CourseFk 
                      from SCS_CourseSection cs     
                      INNER JOIN    @coursesectionID csec 
                              on cs.CourseFk = csec.id 
                      where cs.CourseSectionPk =   csec.id)' 
              ELSE 'SELECT TOP 1 FROM SCSBoard'
            END
```

This is just an example of the code to demonstrate my problem that I am getting an error message saying incorrect syntax near EXEC.

I was wondering why I am not allowed to execute different queries in here and if anyone has a solution to this problem? Thanks very much

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ahh I'll edit the question name then. something like dynamic sql not working. I more phrased it this way because I'm open to other suggestions

Comment: You sure? I've no errors there. I can set it fine. It's just around the EXEC I have the problem

Comment: Sorry my mistake, didnt saw the whole text.

Comment: So you are trying to use `EXEC`, inside a `SELECT`?

Comment: Yes..... I was under the impression this was perfectly ok to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return value from exec(@sql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130462/return-value-from-execsql)

Comment: I dont think so, save the result in a variable first.

Comment: BTW Your `ELSE` query need to indicate `SELECT Top1 Name` or something else

Comment: Ahh that's just a type it actually does in the stored procedure......